# how to render MVC views from SurfaceController?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco-mvc

I have installed Umbraco 7 in MVC application. Have you achieved ever rendering MVC View from Surface Controller ? If it is possible to do how it can be done by passing model and passing a query string parameter to View ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to use an approach called [Route Hijacking](http://shazwazza.com/post/hijacking-umbraco-routes/), rather than surface controllers.

Simplified, the steps are:

- Create a model matching a given Document Type.
- Create a mapper to map an Umbraco IPublishedContent object to the model.
- Create a controller that inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController.
- Override the Index action with a signature of ActionResult Index(Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel model).
- Call the mapper, and return your view.

In your view / template, you will then be able to use

```
@model MyNewModel
```

instead of

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
```

[Here is a very good tutorial](http://ndesoft.dk/2013/05/25/how-to-create-a-real-mvc-app-using-umbraco/) / explanation on the approach.

Be sure to read [the follow up post](http://ndesoft.dk/2013/08/10/real-mvc-app-using-umbraco-revisited/) too